# $2\times2$ Matrix Problem and Recurrence relationship

Tags: matrices

For the $2\times2$ Matrix $A$, $a=1, b=1,c=1$ and $d=0$

Find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $T$ such that $A = TDT^{−1}$.

Hence solve the recurrence relation $f_{n+1} = f_n + f_{n−1}$, $f_0 = 0$, $f_1 = 1$, $n \ge 1$.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Find the two eigenvalues from $|A - \lambda I | = 0$.
- Since the eigenvalues are unique, you can find two linearly independent eigenvectors of $[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$ using Gaussian Elimination.
- Write the diagonal matrix (since eigenvalues are unique) as:

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\ 0 &  \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

- Write $T$ as column vectors using the eigenvectors of each eigenvalue as:

$$T = [ v_1 ~~ v_2]$$

- Verify:

$$A = TDT^{−1}$$

- Now, given we have $A$ as a diagonal matrix, you can use it to compute the powers of $A^n$. This provides a quick method to generate the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. We have:

$$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 &  0 \end{bmatrix}^n = TD^nT^{−1} = \begin{bmatrix}f_{n+1} & f_n\\ f_n &  f_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$

- You can use an inductive proof to prove this.